# Linked lists are not created, why? [CS50 pset4]

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes, cs50

I am doing the pset4 of CS50 which basically needs you to create 26 nodes (each node for every letter of the alphabet) and created a linked list within these nodes to connect words from a dictionary.

So, for example, node 0 will store every word of the dictionary that starts with A, node 1 wills store every word of the dictionary that starts with B, etc...

So, here is the main piece of code:

```
   // Insert words into hash table
while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
{

    // for every word, we allocate enough memory for a node, that will carry the word
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(new_node == NULL) { printf("could not allocate memory.\n"); return false; }

    strcpy(new_node->word, word);
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if(!hashtable[alphabetPosition(word[0])]){
        hashtable[alphabetPosition(word[0])] = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        for(node *ptr = hashtable[alphabetPosition(word[0])]; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next){
            hashtable[alphabetPosition(word[0])]->next = new_node;
        }
    }

}
```

alphabetPosition() is basically a function that will return the first character of the word.

the main problem is this:

```
else
{
    for(node *ptr = hashtable[alphabetPosition(word[0])]; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next){
        hashtable[alphabetPosition(word[0])]->next = new_node;
    }
}
```

Because every thing else is working. The nodes are been created, but the linked lists are not.

I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with this piece of code but I can't seem to understand. If someone could help me (explaining how to solve it), it would help me so much.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use debugger to execute the program step by step and check that each step is working as expected

Comment: You may have more success searching/asking on https://cs50.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main flaw is: `hashtable[index]` is only and always pointing to the last node created. I.E. `hashtable[alphabetPosition(word[0])]->next` is always set to `new_node`.

The `for` loop is basically wrong. The program simply needs to point the `new_node` to the current head of the list (ie `hashtable[alphabetPosition(word[0])` and then make new_node the new head.